# Ruby Encoding While File Writing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a bunch of pdf/txt/msg files I'm trying to download in the ruby console and either move to a local directory or re-upload to another destination.

To start, I've just been trying to read the file and write it to a local directory like so:

```
path = File.join 'temp', doc_name
file = File.new(path, 'w')
file << Document.find(123).fetch_file  // this function retrieves and decrypts the file from s3
```

The exception I get is: Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xB5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I'm wondering how I might be able to get the encoding correct on the file write so that I can download it and open it. It seems like it should be trivial, the answer could be in the decryption or s3 call, but this seemed related to the file write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary to get the right encoding.

```
file = File.new(path, 'wb')
```

Check the encoding like this

```
puts file.encoding
```

It should be 'ASCII-8BIT'.
Do the same with your decrypted filecontent, it should be the same encoding, other wise you need to convert it like this.

```
Document.find(123).fetch_file.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
```

You could also use `File.binread(file)` and `File.binwrite(file, content)`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-binread

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-c-binwrite

Comment: I suspect `fetch_file` already gives him `ASCII-8BIT`, otherwise he wouldn't be getting that message; so `force_encoding` should not be necessary.

Comment: Peter, you are a gentleman and a scholar.  
  
Amadan, you were right, it does give back ASCII-8BIT. I didn't need force_encoding. I using the wb option on the File.new worked like a charm.